# Maxwell solution in differential forms

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, gauge-theory, maxwell-equations

Maxwell equation's in differential form: $dE = 0  \ and\ \ (\ast d \ast)E = p$ in static situation.

Where $E \in \Omega^1(U)$, $p \in \Omega^0(U)$, $\ast$ is hodge star operator, $U= \mathbb{R}^3$

what does $E$ looks like in open subset $U =  \mathbb{R}^3  \backslash L$ where L is a line ($z$-axis)?

Edit: If U = $ \mathbb{R}^3$, and dE = $0$ then E is exact since de Rham coholomly of U = {0} thus, E = $d\phi$ where $\phi \in \Omega^0(U)$. Note that I am looking for general solution, so I think there is no need for boundary condition. Similarily, If U =$   \mathbb{R}^3  \backslash L$, and dE = $0$ then E = $aw + d\phi$ where $ a \in \mathbb{R}$ and w is closed 1-form (non-exact) and $d\phi$ is the exact form as before. This is because de Rham coholmolgy of U (in this case) is isomorphoric to $ \mathbb{R}$. I am trying to figure out w.

Comment: Boundary conditions for $E$ and $p$ are necessary for the solution of differential equations, otherwise the question cannot be answered.